# Change Target attribute to iframename for Wordpress Menu Items

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, menu

As some may know, WordPress only allows you to set menu link targets to _blank. I am trying to open menu links in my iframe which has name="analyticsFrame".

I have added the following code into my functions.php file but the links are still redirecting to the src website as opposed to opening the src link inside my iframe "analyticsFrame".

```html
function add_specific_menu_location_atts( $atts, $item, $args ) {
    // check if the item is in the primary menu
    if( $args->theme_location == 'primary' ) {
      // add the desired attributes:
      $atts['target'] = 'analyticsFrame';
    }
    return $atts;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'add_specific_menu_location_atts', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding your code to `functions.php` with this HTML on a page template worked in my test:

```html
<iframe name="analyticsFrame"></iframe>
```

Confirm that your iframe is in the source code for the page you are testing on (simple mistake).

Comment: Thanks a lot for confirming my code was actually right. I removed the argument to check if the location was "primary" as i suspected this may have been the cause as I am using a theme with a slide in menu which is clearly changing the location from "primary". Removing the argument made the menu work as intended.